# Patch to Publishing DB's doesnt seem to work

Tags: publishing, unicorn

So I have my unicorn autopublish file below and the patch I added to it. I still seem to have trouble with the files actually getting published to the databases for web_uk and web_west. Just wondering if I need anything else on my patch file or if I should look into the unicorn upgrade as a possibility of not getting all the files up correctly.

```
<unicornSyncEnd>
            <!-- when all configurations have synced, fire off a publish that processes the queue we've accumulated -->
            <processor type="Unicorn.Pipelines.UnicornSyncEnd.TriggerAutoPublishSyncedItems, Unicorn">
                <PublishTriggerItemId>/sitecore/templates/Common/Folder</PublishTriggerItemId> <!-- the trigger item can be any leaf node Sitecore item - just has to have a 'starting point' for the publish -->
                <!-- these are the database(s) to publish synced items to -->
                <TargetDatabases hint="list:AddTargetDatabase">
                    <web>web</web>
                </TargetDatabases>
            </processor>
        </unicornSyncEnd>
```

PATCH FOR THIS FILE

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"
               xmlns:environment="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/environment/">
  <sitecore>
    <unicorn patch:source="Sitecore.Unicorn.AutoPublish.config">
      <TargetDatabases hint="list:AddTargetDatabase" environment:require="prodcm or prodcd">
        <web_west>web_west</web_west>
        <web_uk>web_uk</web_uk>
      </TargetDatabases>
    </unicorn>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention your specific Sitecore version nor Unicorn version.  But in the right set of circumstances, e.g. a Sitecore 10.x and a Unicorn version below 4.1.5, you could definitely run into publishing problems due to API changes in Sitecore.

Unicorn release 4.1.6 should solve your problems.

https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/releases/tag/4.1.6

Related issue: https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/issues/407

Comment: Unicorn 4.1.1 and Sitecore 9.3. I have heard the upgrade of unicorn might be the best option so looking at that option now. Thanks

Comment: Don't add thank you comments - use voting to indicate that an answer has helped you please. @user1566783